# Negative time differences with `last reboot`

Tags: linux, reboot, clock

Looking at `last reboot | head -3`, I get the following result:

```
reboot   system boot  5.7.10-201.fc32. Fri Jul 31 11:29   still running
reboot   system boot  5.7.10-201.fc32. Fri Jul 31 11:22 - 09:29  (-1:53)
reboot   system boot  5.7.10-201.fc32. Tue Jul 28 23:14 - 09:21 (2+10:07)
```

I thought at first that the times and dates were showed as "boot - shutdown", but this doesn't make sense considering the second line that shows a negative time difference.

`procinfo` returns the correct boot time:

```
$ procinfo | grep Bootup
Bootup: Fri Jul 31 09:29:39 2020    Load average: 0.01 0.06 0.06 1/1071 28719
```

The hardware clock shows the correct time:

```
$ date; sudo hwclock --show
Fri 31 Jul 2020 11:55:17 AM CEST
2020-07-31 11:55:17.436472+02:00
```

The problem seems to lie with `last reboot` and `who -b`:

```
$ date; uptime; who -b
Fri 31 Jul 2020 11:55:43 AM CEST
 11:55:43 up  2:26,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.04, 0.05
         system boot  2020-07-31 11:29
```

`/var/run/utmp`, read by default by `who -b`, doesn't exist on my system and `/var/log/wtmp`, read by `last reboot`, has the following permissions:

```
$ ll /var/log/wtmp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root utmp 39K Jul 31 11:23 /var/log/wtmp
```

What could be the reason of these discrepancies?

**EDIT**

The correct shutdown time is 09:29 UTC+2. The 11:29 and 11:22 times from `last reboot` should be 09:29 and 09:22, respectively. As observed by @telcoM, one could think that early boot might be using UTC timezone, but then the 11:29 should be 07:29...

Another detail: I'm running a simple Fedora 32 physical machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timezone is CEST, so the current UTC offset should be 2 hours ahead of UTC.

Would the timestamps make sense if assumed that 09:21 actually means 11:21 and 09:29 means 11:29 respectively?

If so, then your early boot might be initially using UTC timezone, but correcting the timezone to CEST at some point after the value of the boot-up timestamp is determined.

Does Fedora still use classic RedHat-style `/etc/sysconfig/clock`? If so, there might be a setting in it that tells whether the hardware clock uses UTC or not. There is also another location for the same information: the third line of `/etc/adjtime` will say either `UTC` or `LOCAL` to specify which time is stored in the hardware clock. If these two locations are not in agreement with each other, I've seen behavior like this. If you find an error here, rebuild your initramfs so that the fix will be included in there too.

Is your `/etc/localtime` a symbolic link to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/your/timezone`, or an actual copy of that file? It might make a difference for the initramfs generator. If the initramfs generator just copies a symbolic link into initramfs without also copying the actual file, the symlink will be broken at the initramfs boot phase, and so the system may default to UTC until the real root filesystem is mounted.

(And if you don't find an error, but the modification timestamp of /etc/localtime, /etc/adjtime or /etc/sysconfig/clock is newer than your initramfs's, rebuild your initramfs again anyway, as someone may have forgotten to do that when changing the clock/timezone settings.)

Also, if this is a virtual machine, or a physical machine on blade hardware, there might be a mechanism in place to sync the time of the VM/blade to the clock of the hypervisor/blade chassis at boot time. Often such mechanism will supply local time, for the benefit of Windows systems. If you use NTP synchronization, the system might boot using local-time-as-UTC or vice versa, but as soon as network interfaces come up, it might get a valid UTC time from a NTP server, again causing a 2-hour jump.

Comment: The correct shutdown time is in fact 09:29 (UTC+2). This means that the 11:29 displayed is UTC+4, which doesn't make sense... One would expect 07:29 instead if last boot was initially using UTC timezone, or am I missing something? Unfortunately Fedora 32 doesn't seem to use `/etc/sysconfig/clock`. `/etc/adjtime` contains LOCAL on the third line. `/etc/localtime` is indeed a symlink to the timezone file and is newer that my current initramfs! I'll rebuild it and keep you updated.

Comment: If the system default timezone has been recently modified, also verify that `date -u` actually indicates correct UTC time. I once saw a case where someone had attempted to copy a new timezone file to `/etc/localtime`, but because the old file was a symlink, ended up overwriting the file of the old timezone in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` instead, which caused some confusion.